# Howto run repair on a single negative token range

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Using DSC 2.1.15 and 256 vnodes, wanted to re-repair 3x single token ranges that had failed a scheduled repair due to other nodes been restarted at the time:

```
    [2017-01-27 16:39:09,722] Repair session eaa19070-e48c-11e6-9ec5-bfac298274c1 for range (3022841941952215056,3024244454843113663] failed with error java.io.IOException: Endpoint /10.3.2.3 died
    [2017-01-27 16:39:09,723] Repair session f9c7ad30-e49d-11e6-9ec5-bfac298274c1 for range (-345691793961228362,-337602087123507428] failed with error java.io.IOException: Endpoint /10.3.2.8 died
    [2017-01-27 16:39:09,723] Repair session b47183d0-e49f-11e6-9ec5-bfac298274c1 for range (1403949860533115064,1426039868590872470] failed with error java.io.IOException: Endpoint /10.3.2.9 died
```

Only when launching the negative range it claimed to want to repair 3527 range rather than expected 1, wondering why as I expected KS only holds the 256 ranges normally repaired-. Hints appreciated TIA!

```
    nodetool repair -pr -par -st -34569179396122836 -et -337602087123507428 mykeyspc
    [2017-01-30 09:20:55,075] Starting repair command #17, repairing 3527 ranges for keyspace mykeyspc (parallelism=PARALLEL, full=true)
```

Solution:

F... cutNpaste, error missed out the last digit in start token, doing it properly works so much better:

```
    nodetool repair -pr -par -st -345691793961228362 -et -337602087123507428 mykeyspc
    [2017-01-31 12:22:19,043] Starting repair command #1, repairing 1 ranges for keyspace mykeyspc (parallelism=PARALLEL, full=true)
```

Comment: Try to remove -par option.

Comment: -par worked fine for the two positive ranges only reporting repairing 1 range.I interrupted this nodetool cmd, but o.a.c.metric.ThreadPools.internal.AntiEntropySessions still seems to indicate an ActiveTask. Howto stop this?